# How to specify users for push notification on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, push-notification

I want to send push notifications to the application users and i can send to all users, but i want to select users also. How can i do that?

Comment: UDIDs are stored in your database, so you can choose users to send notifications, insn't it ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are currently able to send push notifications to all of your users, you're obviously storing their device tokens somewhere. If you want to send a notification to a single user, you just need to determine which token is theirs (possibly by associating information with it in the database—e.g. their email) and send a single notification to APNS.